# dataExtractionRules in Android12

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-12, android-backup-service

When we don't want to maintain `SharedPreferences` or any backup file, we can just set `android:allowBackup="false"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`. 
But `android:allowBackup="false"` is deprecated in Android12. Even though it's deprecated, we can still keep using it just for the `cloud-based backup`. for example, if we're using `SharedPreferences`, after deleting our app and re-installing it, the `SharedPreferences` are gone.
You can find the information from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element).

So, What i want to know is about [D2D](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#backup-restore). In Android12, The android system automatically send files from old device to new device(D2D). I want to stop the system from sending files(like `SharedPreferences`) automactically by default. So, I have to make `dataExtractionRules`  which files include or not.

What i want to do is to exclude all files. it means that i can just transfer the app to new device but there are no data or cache like i just downloaded a new app. So, How can i write `dataExtractionRules` to acheive it?

please check the following code what i did.

## data_exctration_rules.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data-extraction-rules>

<!-- <cloud-backup> I don't write cloud-backups in here
 because i can still use android:allowBackup="false" </cloud-backup> -->
    
    <device-transfer>
        <exclude domain="root" path="where?" />
        <exclude domain="file" path="where?" />
        <exclude domain="database" path="where?" />
        <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="com.google.android.gms.appid.xml" />
        <exclude domain="sharedpref" path="user_pref.xml" />
        <!-- <exclude domain="external" path="where?" /> -->
    </device-transfer>
</data-extraction-rules>
```

Q1. Can i use several `<exclude domain="sharedpref">`? because i have 4 files of SharedPrefereces.

Q2. How exactly should I write down the path?
ex) "data/data/com.myapp/sharedpref/user_pref.xml" or just "user_pref.xml"

Q3. What does "`<exclude domain="root" path="" />`" mean?
does root mean my app? if it is, Don't I need to write another file(like file, database, sharedpref, external etc)?

Answer (score 2):

You should read [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles).

The brief answers about your questions.

> Q1. Can i use several `<exclude domain="sharedpref">?` because i have 4 files of SharedPrefereces.

Yes, you can. You should indicate several declaration or just one with `./` `path` attribute(all files in this directory).

> Q2. How exactly should I write down the path? ex) "data/data/com.myapp/sharedpref/user_pref.xml" or just "user_pref.xml"

You can check your shared preferences xml file name in device file explorer of Android Studio tool.

Just `user_pref.xml` the `domain` automatically generate a path for the matched filename.

> Q3. What does `<exclude domain="root" path="" />` mean? does root mean my app? if it is, Don't I need to write another file(like file, database, sharedpref, external etc)?

I think, you need just `root` domain and `./` path for ignoring all file backup.

But I recommended like that

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data-extraction-rules>
    <cloud-backup>
        <exclude
            domain="root"
            path="./" />
        <exclude
            domain="file"
            path="./" />
        <exclude
            domain="database"
            path="." />
        <exclude
            domain="sharedpref"
            path="." />
        <exclude
            domain="external"
            path="./" />
    </cloud-backup>
    <device-transfer>
        <exclude
            domain="root"
            path="./" />
        <exclude
            domain="file"
            path="./" />
        <exclude
            domain="database"
            path="." />
        <exclude
            domain="sharedpref"
            path="." />
        <exclude
            domain="external"
            path="./" />
    </device-transfer>
</data-extraction-rules>
```

[image]
Figure 1)